# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from AudioBuffer

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am trying to do the record using AudioUnit for iPhone app.

Changes: (start) I have added the following code

```
    bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = 1024;
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = calloc(256, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Changes: (end)

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(appdelegate->audioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             appdelegate->bufferList);
    if(status != 0)
    NSLog(@"AudioUnitRender status is %d", status);
    SInt16* samples = (SInt16*)(ioData->mBuffers[0].mData);
    .....
}
```

fixed: (I am getting OSStatus -50 error code)- Because I didn't initialize the bufferList.

I am  EXC_BAD_ACCESS from AudioBuffer (ioData->mBuffers[0].mData).

I am not sure with this error. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: What is your bufferList initialized to?  Elements of that list are usually where the recorded samples get put.

Comment: I did not initialize anything in bufferList. But I am reading data from ioData.

Comment: I got the issue. Actually AudioBufferList (I mean ioData) is not having data. Thats why, it is giving this error. But I don't have idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it;

In my code, I have written two callback methods. We need two audio device to use two audio unit.

Just I removed one callback function.

Just take a look at the following link to know about it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2091.html

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a message to a deallocated object. In XCode go to Project -> Edit Active Executable -> Arguments -> Click on the "plus" button, and add NSZombieEnabled and set it's value to YES. Doing so, you can debug your application and find out which deallocated object is still receiving messages.

But don't forget to disable this argument on you project afterwards.

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix the issue. Issue is; AudioBufferList (ioData) is not having data. So only it is giving error.